# How can I remove all these 'False' Boolean

Tags: python, python-3.8

how can I remove all the 'False' bool values from my list?

I converted the values of a csv chart into booleans and then into a list with this funtion:

```
new_list=list1.values.tolist()
```

But how can I remove all the 'False' & '0' and just show me all 'True' & '1' values?

new_list:

```
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, False, False, False, True],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, False, False, True, True],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, True, False, False, True],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, False, False, False, True],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, True, False, False, False, False, True],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, False, False, False, True],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, False, False, False, True],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, False, False, False, True],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, True, True, False, True, True],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, False, False, False, True],
```

Comment: Do you want to remove both 0 and False, or only False?

Comment: @Lev M. both, 0 and False.

Comment: What do you mean 'show'?

Comment: Why do you have a pandas Series named `list`? Not only does that trample on the builtin `list`, but it's a complete misnomer

Comment: @roganjosh it was just an example name (the list is not named like this). I changed it :P

Comment: So I see, though it still isn't actually a `list` at all, so `list1` is still confusing. But anyway. Why do you have a mix of ints and bools is my next question? Is that actually the intentional output for your code?

Comment: The bottom line is that this should be handled in pandas _before_ `.values.tolist()` but it's not clear exactly how far upstream from this issue that things should be fixed

Comment: `tru_list = [[item for item in row if item] for row in new_list]` or `[list(filter(None,row)) for row in new_list]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple list comprehension like this:

```
a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, True, False, False, True]
b = [ x for x in a if x]
```

This will leave only values that evaluate to 'True' which is boolean true, any integer that is not 0, and any non empty string.

If you have a list of lists you can nest them like this:

```
new_list = [
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, False, False, False, True],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, False, False, True, True],
   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, True, False, False, True],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, False, False, False, True],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, True, False, False, False, False, True],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, False, False, False, True],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, False, False, False, True],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, False, False, False, True],
   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, True, True, False, True, True],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, False, False, False, True]]

clean_list = [[x for x in y if x] for y in new_list ]
```

Answer (score 0):

## List Comprehension Method

Assuming that you are showing a list of lists above, you can use list comprehension:

```
# lol is a your lists shown above stored in one list    
new_lol = [[x for x in l if x in (1, True)] for l in lol]

    for l in new_lol:
        print(l)
```